# Passing multiple directories to the -prune option in find

Tags: find, directory, array, arguments

I am using `find` to locate and delete backup files but wish to exclude certain directories from the search. The backup filenames could terminate in `.bck`, `bak`, `~`, or `backup`.

The Minimal Working Example (MWE) code with only three directories to exclude is:

```
#! /bin/bash
find . -type d \( -path "./.*" -o -path "./Music" -o -path "./Documents" \) -prune -o -type f \( -name "*.bck" -o -name "*.bak" -o -name "*~" -o -name "*.backup" \) -print0 | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty trash-put
```

The syntax `\( -path "dir1" -o -path "dir2" ... -o -path "dirN" \) -prune` seems a little clunky, especially if there are around ten directories to exclude, although I have shown only three in the MWE.

Is there a more elegant way using either an input file, with the list of excluded directories, or an array- or list-like construct, that could be pressed into service?

I am sorry for not being more explicit when I wrote my original question.

NB: `trash-put` is a utility that moves the files to the `Trashcan` instead of deleting them [1].

[1]. https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no option to tell `find` to read patterns from a file. An easy workaround is to save the patterns I want to exclude in a file and pass that file as input for a reverse `grep`. As an example, I have created the following files and directories:

```
$ tree -a
.
├── a
├── .aa
├── .aa.bak
├── a.bck
├── b
├── .dir1
│   └── bb1.bak
├── dir2
│   └── bb2.bak
├── b.bak
├── c
├── c~
├── Documents
│   └── Documents.bak
├── exclude.txt
├── foo.backup
└── Music
    └── Music.bak
```

If I understood the example you posted correctly, you want to move `a.bck`, `.aa.bak`, `b.bak`, `c~`, `foo.backup` and `dir2/bb2.bak` to the trash and leave `.aa.bak`, `.dir1/bb1.bak`, `Documents/Documents.bak` and `Music/Music.bak` where they are. I have, therefore, created the file `exclude.txt` with the following contents (you can add as many as you want):

```
$ cat exclude.txt 
./.*/
./Music
./Documents
```

I use `./.*/` because I understood your original find to mean that you want to move hidden backup files (`.foo`) that are in the current directory but exclude any backup files that are in hidden directories (`.foo/bar`). So, I can now run the `find` command and use `grep` to exclude unwanted files:

```
$ find . -type f | grep -vZf exclude.txt | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty trash-put
```

---

Grep options:

```
   -v, --invert-match
          Invert  the  sense  of matching, to select non-matching
          lines.  (-v is specified by POSIX.)
   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain patterns from FILE, one  per  line.   The  empty
          file  contains  zero  patterns,  and  therefore matches
          nothing.  (-f is specified by POSIX.)
   -Z, --null
          Output a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of
          the  character  that normally follows a file name.  For
          example, grep -lZ outputs a zero byte after  each  file
          name  instead  of the usual newline.  This option makes
          the output unambiguous, even in the  presence  of  file
          names  containing  unusual  characters  like  newlines.
          This  option  can  be  used  with  commands  like  find
          -print0,  perl  -0,  sort  -z,  and xargs -0 to process
          arbitrary file names, even those that  contain  newline
          characters.
```

Comment: I am so sorry for not being explicit. Kindly see revised question which I hope is clearer.

Comment: @chandra see updated answer, same general idea, different details.

Comment: Thank you. You have answered my question very clearly and perfectly for my purpose. I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 9):

**Pass multiple `-path ... -prune` using `-o` (*or*) logic grouped together by parentheses `\( ... \)`**

```
find /somepath \( -path /a -prune -o \
                  -path /b -prune -o \
                  -path /c -prune \
               \) \
               -o -print
```

The example will not iterate directories or files at or under `/somepath/a`, `/somepath/b`, and `/somepath/c`.

Here is a contrived example using multiple expressions and a complex `-exec` action. This prints the file path and checksum for plain files on a Linux host, pruning paths with mostly transient files or character  devices

```
$ find / \( -path /dev -prune -o \
            -path /proc -prune -o \
            -path /sys -prune \
         \) \
         -o -type f \
            -printf '%p ' -exec sh -c 'md5sum -- "{}" | cut -f1 -d" "' \;
/etc/services 00060e37207f950bf0ebfd25810c19b9
/etc/lsb-release f317530ede1f20079f73063065c1684e
/etc/protocols bb9c019d6524e913fd72441d58b68216
/etc/rsyslog.conf 8f03326e3d7284ef50ac6777ef8a4fb8
...
```

Comment: In the _specific_ example that you show at the end, it would probably be easier to just use `-xdev` to keep `find` from wandering into other mounted filesystems.

Comment: To exclude every `node_modules` folders, even in sub-folders, I had to use `-o -path '*/node_modules*' -prune` instead

Answer (score 7):

With GNU find (i.e. under non-embedded Linux or Cygwin), you can use `-regex` to combine all these `-path` wildcards into a single regex.

```
find . -regextype posix-extended \
     -type d -regex '\./(\..*|Music|Documents)' -prune -o \
     -type f -regex '.*(\.(bck|bak|backup)|~)' -print0 |
xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty trash-put
```

On BSDs or macOS, use `-E` instead of `-regextype posix-extended`.

You may also want to replace that `-print0 | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty trash-put` (where `--no-run-if-empty` is GNU-specific1¹) with its standard shorter equivalent: `-exec trash-put {} +`.

---

<sup>¹ its shorter `-r` form is however supported by some other implementations, even the default on some BSDs</sup>

Comment: Thank you for an excellent alternative answer. It is a shame that I cannot accept two answers.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be more a shell question than a `find` question. With a file containing `( -name dir1 -o -name dir2 ) -prune` (no "\"!) you can simply do this:

```
find ... $(< /path/to/file)
```

Without changing the find call itself (to `eval find` or by changing $IFS) this works with paths without whitespace only, though.

If you want to keep the file simpler you can write a script.

```
# file content
dir1
dir2
dir3

# script content
#!/bin/bash
file=/path/to/file
# file may be checked for whitespace here
grep '[^[:space:]]' "$file" | { empty=yes
  while read dir; do
    if [ yes = "$empty" ]; then
      echo -n "( "
      empty=no
    else
      echo -n " -o "
    fi
    echo -n "-name ${dir}"
  done
  if [ no = "$empty" ]; then
    echo -n " ) -prune"
  fi; }
```

And use

```
find ... $(/path/to/script)
```

instead.

Comment: I am so sorry for not being explicit. Kindly see revised question which I hope is clearer.

Comment: @chandra I neither see how your question is clearer nor do I understand what could be a problem with my solution (except for the trivial replecement of `-name` by `path`).

Comment: My script above works and does what I want it to. I simply wanted to know whether there was a neater way than `\( -path "dir1" -o -path "dir2" ... -o -path "dirN" \) -prune` to exclude certain directories from the recursive search that `find` does. I am not searching for anything *within* files but rather deleting certain files and avoiding certain directories in my search path.  I do not understand what your script is trying to do either. So, it appears we have a miscommunication. Sorry. Let us leave it at that.